# VSTO Outlook User Properties (Custom) not syncing

Tags: c#, vsto, exchange-server, synchronization, outlook-addin

I have the problem that when i add a custom `UserProperty` to an Outlook `MailItem`, it does not get synced to other connected Outlooks.

What can i do to force Outlook to sync the whole email?

**My overal problem:**
I've got a shared Exchange Mailbox, opened on two clients (in Outlook)
I would like to lock a mail item, if it gets opened in one Outlook and show the second Outlook user a message like "The user XX is currently reading this email"

**My way to solve the problem:**
Creating a Outlook Plugin.
When user "A" is opening the Email, I am adding a "LockingUser" `UserProperty` to the `MailItem` object. If user "B" is trying to open the Email, I am first looking if a "LockingUser" Property exists.
I have disabled the cached mode.
I have tried to update the subject of the email: this works perfectly and gets synced immediatly (but is not a solution for my problem)

```
private void SetLockingUser(Outlook.MailItem mail)
{
    var lockingUserProperty = mail.UserProperties.Find("LockingUser");
    if (lockingUserProperty != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Email locked by: " + lockingUserProperty.Value);
        return;
    }

    var identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    var username = identity != null ? identity.Name : "";

    lockingUserProperty = mail.UserProperties.Add("LockingUser", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, false, 1);
    lockingUserProperty.Value = username;
    mail.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please show the relevant snippet of your code and make sure you call MailItem.Save. Also keep in mind that there will always be lag since the changes will take up to a couple minutes to sync to Exchange and then to another user if cached mode is used. You'd be better off using some external sync mechanism instead of a user property.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question: I am working in not cached-mode. When I change the subject of the mail, it gets synced immediatly (1-2 seconds) - so I am guessing there need to be a way to also sync other information!?

Comment: If the other user has the same message opened or referenced in code, Outlook will not see the changes until the message is completely dereferenced and reopened. Can you see the changes in the other mailbox in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button)?